# How to revert a "sudo chmod 644 .*"?

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, chmod

guys!

This is my first post here and, unfortunately, and it's being made in very ugly circumstances!
I'm running Debian Jessie x64 and an hour ago I installed some fonts for figlet into the /usr/share/figlet directory. I couldn't use them because I was unzipping them with sudo and they didn't have the proper permissions. Without giving it much thought I ran sudo chmod 644 .*
Now nothing works(the browser, even Terminator can't find its icons, etc). I read a few minutes ago that the sudo working directory is the root's home and now I'm frankly panicking!

I have two questions: what exactly did I do(did I change all the permissions on everything on my system to 644?) and how do I revert it barring a full backup restore?

I ran two searches looking for files and directories that were modified in the last hour, but that wasn't very productive. I googled for answers, but couldn't find an answer pertaining to the exact command that I ran, hence I'm posting a dedicated question-I want to know exactly what happened.

I'm very curious about what I did because the newly-unpacked figlet fonts themselves were left with their permissions unchanged!

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What is the directory that you run the command from  ?

Comment: It was run from the /usr/share/figlet directory. But it was run with sudo and that changes the working directory to root's, hence the question.

Comment: it did not. `sudo` doesn't change the directory

Comment: @WissamAl-Roujoulah Hey man, your tip totally worked! It was the share directory's permissions that got screwed up. Why did you remove your comment? I'd like to thank you separately-can I +1 or +rep you somehow? I'm just not very familiar with how this works here!

Comment: @Max welcome to Unix.SE! Wissam deleted his answer which wasn't quite correct (`chmod 755 /usr/share/*` wouldn't restore the permissions on `/usr/share` itself), so you can't reward him directly.

Comment: @StephenKitt Oh, that makes sense! Thank you! I'll stop spamming now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're running Bash (with typical settings), running

```
sudo chmod 644 .*
```

from `/usr/share/figlet` would end up running

```
sudo chmod 644 . ..
```

(`echo .*` will display `. ..`).

This is equivalent to

```
sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/figlet /usr/share
```

Fixing your system is straightforward:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/share /usr/share/figlet
```

Comment: Thank you, this exhaustively answers both of my questions! Now I know exactly what the command does with the arguments that I've used!
But I kind of went on the tip of the other guy who answered here first-is there a way I can rep him somehow? I'm very new to how this whole dealio works here.
And a huge thanks to you, again!